# HTML form submits to php user gets email but my email is blank

Tags: php, forms, email

I have a form that submits and send 2 emails: one email to the customer to confirm and the other email to my sales staff.

The email to the customer works just fine, and displays the name and email that are entered in the form in the body of the email

The email to my sales staff lists the information entered on the form. However, when the email is sent to my sales email address the body of the email shows up blank.

HTML:

```
<form id="RFQ" method="post" action="RFQ-result.php">
        <h1 align="center">Request a Quote</h1>
         <table width="640" border="0" cellpadding="2" align="center">
           <tr>
             <td height="32" colspan="6"><strong>PROJECT INFORMATION</strong></td>
             </tr>
           <tr>
             <td width="14">&nbsp;</td>
             <td width="120" align="right">Project Name:</td>
             <td colspan="4"><span id="spryProjectName">
               <input name="ProjectName" type="text" id="ProjectName" size="50" />
               <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">*</span></span></td>
        </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td align="right"><label for="Company2">Company:</label></td>
             <td colspan="4"><span id="spryCompany">
               <input name="Company" type="text" id="Company" size="40" />
               <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">*</span></span></td>
        </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td align="right">Address:</td>
             <td colspan="4"><span id="spryAddress">
               <input name="Address" type="text" id="Address" size="50" />
               <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">*</span></span></td>
        </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td align="right">City: </td>
             <td><span id="spryCity">
               <input type="text" name="City" id="City" />
               <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">*</span></span></td>
             <td width="1">&nbsp;</td>
             <td width="135" align="right">State / Province:</td>
             <td width="154"><span id="spryState">
               <input type="text" name="State" id="State" />
               <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">*</span></span></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td align="right">Postal Code:</td>
             <td width="178"><span id="spryZip">
               <input name="Zip" type="text" id="Zip" size="10" maxlength="6" />
               <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">*</span></span></td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td align="right">Country: </td>
             <td><input type="text" name="Country" id="Country" /></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
           </tr>
         </table>
         <table width="640" border="0" cellpadding="2" align="center">
           <tr>
             <td height="32" colspan="6"><strong>CONTACT INFORMATION</strong></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td width="15">&nbsp;</td>
             <td width="121" align="right">First Name:</td>
             <td width="173"><span id="spryFirstName">
               <input name="FirstName" type="text" id="FirstName" size="20" />
               <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">*</span></span></td>
             <td width="1">&nbsp;</td>
             <td width="89" align="right">Last Name:</td>
             <td width="203"><span id="spryLastName">
               <input type="text" name="LastName" id="LastName" />
               <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">*</span></span></td>
        </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td align="right">Phone:</td>
             <td><span id="spryPhone">
               <input name="Phone" type="text" id="Phone" size="20" />
               <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">*</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span></td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td align="right"><label for="Mobile2">Mobile:</label></td>
             <td><span id="spryMobile">
               <input name="Mobile" type="text" id="Mobile" size="20" />
               <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">*</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">*Invalid format</span></span></td>
        </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td align="right">E-mail: </td>
             <td colspan="4"><span id="spryEmail">
             <input name="Email" type="text" id="Email" size="40" />
             <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">*</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">*</span></span></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
             <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
         <table width="640" border="0" cellpadding="2" align="center">
           <tr> </tr>
         </table>
         <table width="640" border="0" cellpadding="2" align="center">
           <tr>
             <td height="33" colspan="5"><strong>STANDARD CONFIGURATION</strong></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td width="156" colspan="2" align="right">Location of Drive:</td>
             <td width="437" colspan="2"><span id="spryDriveCity">
               <label for="DriveCity"></label>
               <input type="text" name="DriveCity" id="DriveCity" />
               <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">*</span></span>, <span id="spryDriveState">
                 <label for="DriveState"></label>
                 <input type="text" name="DriveState" id="DriveState" />
                 <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">*</span></span></td>
             </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td colspan="2" align="right">Temperature Range:</td>
             <td colspan="2"><span id="spryMinTemp">
               <label for="MinTemp"></label>
               <input name="MinTemp" type="text" id="MinTemp" size="5" />
               -       <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">*</span></span><span id="spryMaxTemp">
                 <label for="MaxTemp"></label>
                 <input name="MaxTemp" type="text" id="MaxTemp" size="5" />
                 <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">*</span></span> °C</td>
             </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td colspan="2" align="right">Altitude:</td>
             <td colspan="2"><span id="spryAltitude">
               <label for="Altitude"></label>
               <input name="Altitude" type="text" id="Altitude" size="5" />
               <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">*</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format</span></span> ft</td>
             </tr>
           <tr>
             <td width="15">&nbsp;</td>
             <td colspan="2" align="right"><label for="PumpType">Type of Application:</label></td>
             <td colspan="2"><span id="spryPumpType">
               <select name="PumpType" id="PumpType">
                 <option> </option>
                 <option value="Beam Pump">Beam Pump</option>
                 <option value="Progressive Cavity Pump">Progressive Cavity Pump</option>
                 <option value="Rotaflex Pump">Rotaflex Pump</option>
                 <option value="Submersible Pump">Submersible Pump</option>
                 <option value="Surface Centrifugal Compressor">Surface Centrifugal Compressor</option>
                 <option value="Surface Centrifugal Pump">Surface Centrifugal Pump</option>
                 <option value="Surface Reciprocating Compressor">Surface Reciprocating Compressor</option>
                 <option value="Surface Reciprocating Pump">Surface Reciprocating Pump</option>
                 </select>
               <span class="selectRequiredMsg">*</span></span></td>
        </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td colspan="2" align="right">Drive Manufacturer:</td>
             <td colspan="2"><span id="spryManufacturer">
               <label for="Manufacturer"></label>
               <input name="Manufacturer" type="text" id="Manufacturer" size="25" />
               <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">*</span></span></td>
             </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td colspan="2" align="right">Model No:</td>
             <td colspan="2"><span id="spryModel">
               <label for="Model3"></label>
               <input name="Model" type="text" id="Model3" size="20" />
               <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">*</span></span></td>
             </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td colspan="2" align="right">Speed Range:</td>
             <td colspan="2"><span id="sprytextfield18">
               <label for="MinSpeed"></label>
               <input name="MinSpeed" type="text" id="MinSpeed" size="10" />
               <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">*</span></span> - <span id="spryMaxSpeed">
                 <label for="MaxSpeed"></label>
                 <input name="MaxSpeed" type="text" id="MaxSpeed" size="10" />
                 <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">*</span></span> ft/sec</td>
             </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td colspan="2" align="right">Input Voltage:</td>
             <td colspan="2"><span id="spryInputVoltage">
               <label for="InputVoltage"></label>
               <select name="InputVoltage" id="InputVoltage">
                 <option> </option>
                 <option value="200-240 VAC Input">200-240 VAC Input</option>
                 <option value="380-500 VAC Input">380-500 VAC Input</option>
                 <option value="525-690 VAC Input">525-690 VAC Input</option>
                 </select>
               <span class="selectRequiredMsg">*</span></span></td>
             </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td colspan="2" align="right">Input Phase:</td>
             <td colspan="2"><span id="spryInputPhase">
               <select name="InputPhase" id="InputPhase">
                 <option> </option>
                 <option value="Single Phase">Single Phase</option>
                 <option value="Three Phase">Three Phase</option>
                 </select>
               <span class="selectRequiredMsg">*</span></span></td>
             </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td colspan="2" align="right">Frequency:</td>
             <td colspan="2"><span id="spryFrequency">
               <label for="Frequency"></label>
               <input name="Frequency" type="text" id="Frequency" size="10" />
               <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">*</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span> Hz</td>
             </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td colspan="2" align="right">kW:</td>
             <td colspan="2"><span id="sprykW">
               <label for="kW"></label>
               <input name="kW" type="text" id="kW" size="10" />
               <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">*</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span></td>
             </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td colspan="2" align="right">HP:</td>
             <td colspan="2"><span id="spryHP">
               <label for="HP"></label>
               <input name="HP" type="text" id="HP" size="5"/>
               <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">*</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span></td>
             </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td colspan="2" align="right">kVA:</td>
             <td colspan="2"><span id="sprykVA">
               <label for="kVA"></label>
               <input name="kVA" type="text" id="kVA" size="5" width="75"/>
               <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">*</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span></td>
             </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td colspan="2" align="right">Amps:</td>
             <td colspan="2"><span id="spryAmps">
               <label for="Amps3"></label>
               <input name="Amps" type="text" id="Amps3" size="5" width="75"/>
               <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">*</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span> </span></td>
             </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td colspan="2" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
             <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
             </tr>
           </table>
         <table width="640" border="0" cellpadding="2" align="center">
           <tr>
             <td height="32" colspan="5" align="left"><strong>OPTIONS</strong></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td width="14">&nbsp;</td>
             <td colspan="4" align="left">Enclosure &amp; Environment Options:</td>
             </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
             <td width="237"><input type="checkbox" name="Shield" id="Shield" />
               <label for="Shield">Sun/Snow Sheild</label></td>
             <td width="15">&nbsp;</td>
             <td width="327"><input type="checkbox" name="ColdKit" id="ColdKit" />
               <label for="ColdKit">Cold Weather Kit (-40 to -50 °C)</label></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
             <td><input type="checkbox" name="WallStand" id="WallStand" />
               <label for="WallStand">Wall Mounting Stand</label></td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td><input type="checkbox" name="HeatKit" id="HeatKit" />
               <label for="HeatKit">Heat Trace Kit</label></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
             <td><input type="checkbox" name="FloorBase" id="FloorBase" />
               <label for="FloorBase">Floor Mounting Base</label></td>
             <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td width="15" align="left">&nbsp;</td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td colspan="2" align="left">Input:</td>
             <td colspan="2">Output:</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
             <td><input type="checkbox" name="PowerKit" id="PowerKit" />
               <label for="PowerKit">Power Terminal Kit.</label></td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td><input type="checkbox" name="MotorKit" id="MotorKit" />
               <label for="MotorKit">Motor Terminal Kit</label></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
             <td><input type="checkbox" name="Harmonic" id="Harmonic" />
               <label for="Harmonic">Harmonic Filter Enclosure</label></td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td><input type="checkbox" name="SineFilter" id="SineFilter" />
               <label for="SineFilter">Sine Filter Enclosure</label></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td colspan="2" align="left">&nbsp;</td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td colspan="2" align="left">VFD:</td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
             <td colspan="3"><input type="checkbox" name="Fieldbus" id="Fieldbus" />
               <label for="Fieldbus">Fieldbus Networks</label></td>
             </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
             <td colspan="3"><input type="checkbox" name="ControlKit" id="ControlKit" />
               <label for="ControlKit">Control Terminal Kit</label></td>
             </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
             <td colspan="3"><input type="checkbox" name="General" id="General" />
               <label for="General">General Purpose I/O, 3DI, 2DO, 2AI, 1AO</label></td>
             </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
             <td colspan="3"><input type="checkbox" name="Relay" id="Relay" />
               <label for="Relay">Relay Option, 3RO, 240Vac, 2A</label></td>
             </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
             <td colspan="3"><input type="checkbox" name="DCSupply" id="DCSupply" />
               <label for="DCSupply">24 V Ext. DC Supply Connector</label></td>
             </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td colspan="2" align="left">Operation &amp; Support:</td>
             <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
             <td colspan="3"><input type="checkbox" name="iCM" id="iCM" />
               <label for="iCM">SALT iCM (remote access internect control module)</label></td>
             </tr>
         </table>
         <blockquote>
           <p align="right">
             <input name="Submit" type="submit" id="Submit" value="Submit"/>
           </p>
         </blockquote>

</form>
```

PHP:

```
    <?php
$ProjectName = $_POST['ProjectName'];
$Company = $_POST['Company'];
$Address = $_POST['Address'];
$City = $_POST['City'];
$State = $_POST['State'];
$Zip = $_POST['Zip'];
$Country = $_POST['Country'];
$FirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
$LastName = $_POST['LastName'];
$Phone = $_POST['Phone'];
$Mobile = $_POST['Mobile'];
$Email = $_POST['Email'];

$DriveCity = $_POST['DriveCity'];
$DriveState = $_POST['DriveState'];
$MinTemp = $_POST['MinTemp'];
$MaxTemp = $_POST['MaxTemp'];
$Altitude = $_POST['Altitude'];
$PumpType = $_POST['PumpType'];
$Manufacturer = $_POST['Manufacturer'];
$Model = $_POST['Model'];
$MinSpeed = $_POST['MinSpeed'];
$MaxSpeed = $_POST['MaxSpeed'];
$InputVoltage = $_POST['InputVoltage'];
$InputPhase = $_POST['InputPhase'];
$Frequency = $_POST['Frequency'];
$kW = $_POST['kW'];
$HP = $_POST['HP'];
$kVA = $_POST['kVA'];
$Amps = $_POST['Amps'];

$Shield = $_POST['Shield'];
$WallStand = $_POST['WallStand'];
$FloorBase = $_POST['FloorBase'];
$ColdKit = $_POST['ColdKit'];
$HeatKit = $_POST['HeatKit'];

$PowerKit = $_POST['PowerKit'];
$Harmonic = $_POST['Harmonic'];
$MotorKit = $_POST['MotorKit'];
$SineFilter = $_POST['SineFilter'];

$Fieldbus = $_POST['Fieldbus'];
$ControlKit = $_POST['ControlKit'];
$General = $_POST['General'];
$Relay = $_POST['Relay'];
$DCSupply = $_POST['DCSupply'];

$iCM = $_POST['iCM'];


//Sending Email to form owner
$header = "From: $Email\n"
. "Reply-To: $Email\n";
$subject = "SALT RFQ";
$email_to = "sales@pmcsalt.com";
$message = "Project Name: $ProjectName\n" . "Company: $Company\n" . "Address: $Address\n" . "City: $City\n" . "State: $State\n" . "Zip: $Zip\n" . "Country: $Country\n" . "First Name: $FirstName\n" . "Last Name: $LastName\n" . "Phone: $Phone\n" . "Mobile: $Mobile\n" . "Email: $Email\n" . 

"Drive City: $DriveCity\n" . 
"Drive State: $DriveState\n" . 
"Min Temp: $MinTemp\n" . 
"Max Temp: $MaxTemp\n" . 
"Altitude: $Altitude\n" . 
"Application Type: $PumpType\n" . 
"Manufacturer: $Manufacturer\n" . 
"Model: $Model\n" . 
"MinSpeed: $MinSpeed\n" . 
"MaxSpeed: $MaxSpeed\n" . 
"InputVoltage: $InputVoltage\n" . 
"InputPhase: $InputPhase\n" . 
"kW: $kW\n" . 
"HP: $HP\n" . 
"kVA: $kVA\n" . 
"Amps: $Amps\n" . 

"Sun/Snow Shield: $Shield\n" . 
"Wall Mounting Stand: $WallStand\n" . 
"Floor Mounting Base: $FloorBase\n" . 
"Cold Weather Kit: $ColdKit\n" . 
"Heat Trace Kit: $HeatKit\n" . 

"Power Terminal Kit: $PowerKit\n" . 
"Harmonic Filter Enclosure: $Harmonic\n" . 
"Motor Terminal Kit: $MotorKit\n" . 
"Sine Filter Enclosure: $SineFilter\n" . 

"Fieldbus Networks: $Fieldbus\n" . 
"Control Terminal Kit: $ControlKit\n" . 
"General Purpose I/O, 3DI, 2DO, 2AI, 1AO: $General\n" . 
"Relay Option, 3RO, 240Vac, 2A: $Relay\n" . 
"24 V Ext. DC Supply Connector: $DCSupply\n" . 

"SALT iCM: $iCM\n" . 

mail($email_to, $subject ,$message ,$header ) ;

//Sending Confirmation Email to Client
$header = "From: sales@pmcsalt.com\n"
. "Reply-To: sales@pmcsalt.com\n";
$subject = "SALT RFQ";
$email_to = "$Email";
$message = "Dear $FirstName $LastName,\n \n We have received your pricing request for $ProjectName. One of our sales representatives will be with you within 48 hours to discuss pricing for your custom application.\n \n Thank you for chosing Power Management Controls!! \n \n \n";
mail($email_to, $subject ,$message ,$header ) ;

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not terminating your concatentation properly:

```
"24 V Ext. DC Supply Connector: $DCSupply\n" . 

"SALT iCM: $iCM\n" . 

mail($email_to, $subject ,$message ,$header ) ;
```

This should be:

```
24 V Ext. DC Supply Connector: $DCSupply\n" . 

"SALT iCM: $iCM\n";

mail($email_to, $subject ,$message ,$header ) ;
```

At the moment, you've not got anything in `$message` at the point where you're calling `mail()`.

Comment: Thanks, it's all working now! I have been messing with this for 2 days and the only answer was a little semi-colon.

Comment: Sometimes it just takes a fresh pair of eyes to see something. Glad I could help!